# Query to get data from a table as column names in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I created some sample tables and data to try LISTAGG

```
SELECT SALE_TITLE, addr_id, addr_name, addr_desc
         , LISTAGG(SALES_ID, ',')
             WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SALES_ID)
             AS SALES_ID
    FROM   (select a.addr_id, a.addr_name, a.addr_desc, 
                   b.SALES_ID, b.SALE_TITLE, 
                   ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY b.SALES_ID ) rn,
                   COUNT (*) OVER () cnt
            from palm.adrss a, palm.sales b 
            where a.addr_id = b.addr_id) 
   GROUP BY SALE_TITLE, addr_id, addr_name, addr_desc;
```

When I run the above query my result set is following

```
+-----------------+----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+
|     SALE_TITLE  |  ADDR_ID | ADDR_NAME |  ADDR_DESC   |  SALES_ID   |
+-----------------+----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+
|     Role        |        2 | saty      | local test   | 14,34       |
|     Entitlement |        2 | saty      | local test   | 22,42       |
|     Role        |        3 | vasu      | portal       | 14,34       |
|     Entitlement |        3 | vasu      | portal       | 22,42       |
|     Role        |        4 | sand      | Golden gate  | 144,344     |
|     Entitlement |        4 | sand      | Golden gate  | 224,424     |
|     Role        |        5 | Gou       | Data Modeler | 144         |
|     Suffix      |        5 | Gouri     | Data Modeler | 224,424     |
|     Entitlement |        5 | Gou       | Data Modeler | 344         |
|     Role        |        6 | Mad       | Data Analyst | 144         |
|     Entitlement |        6 | Mad       | Data Analyst | 224,344,424 |
+-----------------+----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+
```

Now using this result set I want to write another query to get a result set which looks like below. In this Role, Entitlement, Suffix will be column names and will have sale_id's under them

```
+---------------+--------------+---------+----------------------+---------+
|     ADDR_NAME |  ADDR_DESC   |  Role   | Entitlement          | Suffix  |
+---------------+--------------+---------+----------------------+---------+
|        saty   | local test   | 14,34   | 22,42                |         |
|        vasu   | portal       | 14,34   | 22,42                |         |
|        sand   | Golden gate  | 144,344 | 224,424              |         |
|        Gou    | Data Modeler | 144     | 344                  | 224,424 |
|        Mad    | Data Analyst | 144     | 224,344,424          |         |
+---------------+--------------+---------+----------------------+---------+
```

Please let me know if this is possible and provide me some inputs

Thanks in advance

Comment: Next time try https://senseful.github.io/text-table/ to format your table. Check the table represent your desire data sample.

Comment: explain the logic to go from your data to your expected output.

Comment: You seem to be looking for a [`pivot`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#CHDFAFIE)? Possibly a dynamic pivot if you don't have a fixed list of `sales_title` values to pivot on, though.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - So that's why we see so many posts with tables formatted that way? That is a **terrible idea**. Try copying the inputs and pasting in your SQL IDE and see if it's usable. Tables should **NOT** be formatted that way; the best way is column names, a row of dashes (if desired) to delimit the column names, and then values aligned in columns WITH NOTHING ELSE in the rows. How do you import data formatted as such tables in your IDE? The point being: the OP's data shouldn't only look nice, it should also be easy to copy and paste for testing.

Comment: PSK:  please let us know your Oracle **version** (run `select * from v$version` if you don't know; don't guess!) Do so whenever you post here. For example for the question at hand, the PIVOT operator was introduced in version 11.1, LISTAGG was only introduced in 11.2, ......

Comment: @mathguy not sure why you say is hard to convert those table to your IDE. Just use the Text to DDL function from sqlfiddle https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcXhf.png

Comment: Cross-posted with https://community.oracle.com/thread/4073768

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - OK, thank you for the suggestion, I may play with it a bit. But it still doesn't answer my concern. For one thing, I prefer to include the inputs in a WITH clause and not create and delete tables in my schema all the time. With a WITH clause, anyone can copy and paste the entire code and work with it, instead of having to copy the OP's input table, convert to DDL on sqlfiddle, then copy to their IDE, create the tables, etc. (Even for me, copying from here straight to SQL Developer is much faster than going through sqlfiddle.)

Comment: @mathguy Well the best should be if every OP post the DDL, but we can only dream about it :(. But if you compare the original post with my edit you can see the big difference to try understand the question. Im not familiar with SQL Developer so not sure how works the copying there or what format is need it. But using sqlFiddle I can get the DDL on multiple rdbms.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - SQL Developer is not the issue, it is the same in Toad and SQL\*Plus etc. Best would be if the OP posts the inputs in the form of a WITH clause so we don't all have to create and delete tables in our schemas (unless the problem is specific to data stored on disk - using ROWID for example, or testing query speed including efficient use of I/O operations). No doubt formatted data is much better than non-formatted, but I prefer a format as simple as possible: align data in columns, then use Ctrl-K and nothing else. (Also this is probably a META discussion...)

Answer (score 0):

I saw you have typo on sample data, if you fix it you will get your desired output.

```
update Your_Table
set ADDR_NAME='Gou'
where ADDR_NAME='Gouri'
```

Your query should be:

```
    select t1.ADDR_NAME,t1.ADDR_DESC,
    max(case when t1.SALE_TITLE='Role'  then t2.SALES_ID end) 'Role',
    max(case when t1.SALE_TITLE='Entitlement'  then t2.SALES_ID end) 'Entitlement',
    max(case when t1.SALE_TITLE='Suffix'  then t2.SALES_ID end) 'Suffix'
    from  Your_Table t1
    join  Your_Table t2
    on t1.ADDR_ID=t2.ADDR_ID and t1.SALE_TITLE=t2.SALE_TITLE
    group by  t1.ADDR_NAME,t1.ADDR_DESC
    order by Role
```